# How to change soft key actions

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, buttons

I have a HTC one v, rooted, stock ROM. The home, back and recent app keys are touch on the glass, but not on the actual screen. In some Roms, it gives you the option to change what it does, but not in the one I'm using. Does anyone know how to change it without too much coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I installed xposed framework, got xposed additions from play store, and changed it.